# Storing input data

Tags: java, int, joptionpane

Can anyone help me here?? I have compiled and successfully run a program using Java which takes user inputs from an "inputdialog" box and displays this information back in the console along with a simple mathematical formula. The problem I cannot seem to overcome is when the data is input the user has an option to enter another set of the same data type but I need the console to register this as a second input. This is how far I am currently with the section of code and my ideas on how to make this work using an array but I have been informed that saving/storing the data as an object might be a better option?

```
private void enterCar()
    {
     String carInfo;
     int carHours;
     int i = 0;
     int[] carNumb = new int[20];
     double fee = Double.parseDouble("7.50");
     double sum = 0;
     final int MAX = 12;
    {

        carInfo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the license plate of the car");
        carHours = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of hours the car was parked (1-12):"));

            System.out.printf("\n");
            System.out.printf("Details for car "+carNumb+" entered:\n");
            System.out.printf("License plate   Hours      Fee:\n");
            System.out.printf(""+carInfo+"           "+carHours+"         $");
                    if (carHours == 1)
                        System.out.printf("%3.2f",fee*(carHours));
                    else if (carNum == 2)
                        System.out.printf("%3.2f",fee+4.50);
                    else if (carHours >= 3)
                        System.out.printf("%3.2f",3+(carHours*4.50));
            System.out.printf("\n\n");

    }
}
```

When I compile and run the console I get the line "Details for car [I@6659c656 entered". This line does change to something like "[I@7665c575" the next time I activate the option so I can assume that I may need to assign a value to the number differently?

I have tried the option that is show in the code provided as well as trying to activate a list using (1, 2, 3, ect) but this also just outputs that random line of numbers and letters.

I guess to simplify my question. I need to store 20 individual inputs from an 'InputDialog' box and store it for later access in a console.

Comment: > System.out.printf("Details for car "+carNumb+" entered:\n");
You want to print `carNumb` or `carNum`? `carNumb` is array, right?

Comment: Yeah sorry I feel those names were poor choices. carNum is a value which then gets multiplied to form a dollar value, where as carNumb is the list number of the information entered. Basically I want the user to input a name and a number. That information then gets stored as "Details for car 1 entered:" and then the information displayed. If the user then inputs a second car name and number I want the console to display the information as "Details for car 2 entered:"

Comment: I mean because you print out the Object without override `toString` method, you get [I@7665c575 or sth like this.

Comment: toString? Do I have to assign that to one of the other values? Sorry I am still learning a lot about the basics of Java.

Comment: It's OK, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to store 20 individual inputs from an `InputDialog` box and store it for later access in a console.

Use a loop such as `for`.

> That information then gets stored as "Details for car 1 entered:" and then the information displayed.

As I said before, you should use index of array instead of array. And because array is zero-based index, so I use `carNumb[i] + 1` to print out the order.

Then calculate fee and store to `carNumb` array.

Note that, your `fee` is `double` type => `carNumb` should be `double` type to store correct value.

Full code:

```
public void enterCar() {
  String carInfo;
  int carHours;
  int i = 0;
  double[] carNumb = new double[20];
  double fee = Double.parseDouble("7.50");
  double sum = 0;
  final int MAX = 12;

  for (; i < carNumb.length; i++) {
    carInfo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the license plate of the car");
    carHours = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of hours the car was parked (1-12):"));
    System.out.printf("\n");
    System.out.printf("Details for car " + (carNumb[i] + 1) + " entered:\n");
    System.out.printf("License plate   Hours      Fee:\n");
    System.out.printf("" + carInfo + "           " + carHours + "         $");
    carNumb[i] = getFee(fee, carHours);
    System.out.printf("%3.2f", carNumb[i]);
    System.out.printf("\n\n");
  }
}

private double getFee(double fee, int hours) {
  if (hours == 1) {
    return fee;
  }
  if (hours == 2) {
    return fee + 4.5;
  }
  if (hours >= 3) {
    return 3 + hours * 4.5;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Did I get your idea?

Comment: This is on the way to being what I need. On an old console I used, "for(int carNum=1; carNum <= 6; carNum++)" and it changed the value of carNum to the next number in the list, ie: 1, 2, 3. However, I need the console to take the input data but then return to a menu where the user can then select to input another set of information. When I try to compile the program this way it just continuously asks for input [x] amount of times then returns.